# Thread Contention on a ConcurrentDictionary in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrentdictionary

I have a C# .NET program that uses an external API to process events for real-time stock market data. I use the API callback feature to populate a `ConcurrentDictionary` with the data it receives on a stock-by-stock basis.

I have a set of algorithms that each run in a constant loop until a terminal condition is met. They are called like this (but all from separate calling functions elsewhere in the code):

```
Task.Run(() => ExecutionLoop1());
Task.Run(() => ExecutionLoop2());
...
Task.Run(() => ExecutionLoopN());
```

Each one of those functions calls SnapTotals():

```
public void SnapTotals()
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, MarketData> kvpMarketData in
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, MarketData>(Handler.MessageEventHandler.Realtime))
    {
    ...
```

The `Handler.MessageEventHandler.Realtime` object is the `ConcurrentDictionary` that is updated in real-time by the external API.

At a certain specific point in the day, there is an instant burst of data that comes in from the API. That is the precise time I want my `ExecutionLoop()` functions to do some work.

As I've grown the program and added more of those execution loop functions, and grown the number of elements in the `ConcurrentDictionary`, the performance of the program as a whole has seriously degraded. Specifically, those `ExecutionLoop()` functions all seem to freeze up and take much longer to meet their terminal condition than they should.

I added some logging to all of the functions above, and to the function that updates the `ConcurrentDictionary`. From what I can gather, the `ExecutionLoop()` functions appear to access the `ConcurrentDictionary` so often that they block the API from updating it with real-time data. The loops are dependent on that data to meet their terminal condition so they cannot complete.

I'm stuck trying to figure out a way to re-architect this. I would like for the thread that updates the `ConcurrentDictionary` to have a higher priority but the message events are handled from within the external API. I don't know if `ConcurrentDictionary` was the right type of data structure to use, or what the alternative could be, because obviously a regular Dictionary would not work here. Or is there a way to "pause" my execution loops for a few milliseconds to allow the market data feed to catch up? Or something else?

Comment: Do you need your algorithms to see the updates while algorithm is in progress, or it works on a snapshot of data at the time it started?

Comment: So each of these `ExecutionLoopX` methods are enumerating the shared `ConcurrentDictionary<string, MarketData>` in a tight loop? How many of these methods are running concurrently? How many cores does the CPU of your machine have? How many entries are stored in the dictionary on average, when the `ExecutionLoopX` methods are invoked?

Comment: I need the algorithms to see the updates at the time when it is started in a snapshot. I'd be OK with it seeing the updates while it is in progress, but that really isn't necessary.

I have 11 ExecutionLoop() functions running at once, each in a tight loop.  There ar 6 cores on my PC that I use for development, 4 cores in production (although I can upgrade that PC as necessary), there are roughly 1,100 entries in the dictionary.

Comment: Do I get that right, that you actually iterate a  copy of Dictionary? So, I was asking myself: why not just iterate `...Realtime.ToArray()`? I don't know if that would improve anything, though.

Comment: The other thing, I would try, perhaps: only getting a copy of the keys. And then query the original dictionary in the algorithm, iterating the keys-copy.

Comment: It's hard for me to say if either of those would make a difference due to the thread safe nature of ConcurrentDictionary. No matter what, something is going to lock that object down so it can be read.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Your basic approach is sound except for one fatal flaw: they are all hitting the same dictionary at the same time via iterators, sets, and gets. So you *must* do one thing: in `SnapTotals` you *must* iterate over a *copy* of the concurrent dictionary.

When you iterate over `Handler.MessageEventHandler.Realtime` or even `new ConcurrentDictionary<string, MarketData>(Handler.MessageEventHandler.Realtime)` you are using the `ConcurrentDictionary<>`'s iterator, which even though is thread-safe, is going to be using the dictionary for the entire period of iteration (including however long it takes to do the processing for each and every entry in the dictionary). That is most likely where the contention occurs.

Making a copy of the dictionary is much faster, so should lower contention.

Change `SnapTotals` to

```
public void SnapTotals()
{
    var copy = Handler.MessageEventHandler.Realtime.ToArray();
    foreach (var kvpMarketData in copy)
    {
    ...
```

Now, each `ExecutionLoopX` can execute in peace without write-side contention (your API updates) and without read-side contention from the other loops. The write-side can execute without read-side contention as well.

The only "contention" should be for the short duration needed to do each copy.

And by the way, the dictionary copy (an array) is *not threadsafe*; it's just a plain array, but that is *ok* because each task is executing in isolation on its own copy.

Comment: OP already makes a copy via `new ConcurrentDictionary<string, MarketData>(Handler.MessageEventHandler.Realtime)`. Yes there is no reason to copy it to another concurrent dictionary but it's still a copy so no contention should occur.

Comment: Yes, a copy is made (fair enough), but to make the copy, the original dictionary is iterated. That's not the same as `ToArray`. `ToArray` uses optimizations and does not use an iterator.

Comment: On the other hand, ToArray uses locking, because it returns a snapshot. While iterator is lock free (and can include modifications which happened during iteration but OP is fine with that). So it's arguable what is better for contention.

Comment: Yeah, the idea I had to make a copy of the `ConcurrentDictionary` to hopefully avoid contention but I don't know enough about the internals of making a copy vs `ToArray` or just iterating over the original `ConcurrentDictionary` to decide which is most efficient.

Comment: @jgriffo1 be aware that Microsoft [does not guarantee](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/46374 "Guarantee that ConcurrentDictionary enumerations don't emit duplicate keys") that a single enumeration of a `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` returns unique keys.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I was defensive about how I wrote it, I think I should be OK there. I haven't noticed any logical bugs in my code that would indicate this was happening.

Comment: @jgriffo1 the current implementation of the `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` (.NET 7) does not allow this to happen. It's just that Microsoft doesn't guarantee the current behavior. They reserve the freedom to change the behavior in the future, without notice, if they want.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your main problem is not related to the `ConcurrentDictionary`, but to the large number of `ExecutionLoopX` methods. Each of these methods saturates a CPU core, and since the methods are more than the cores of your machine, the whole CPU is saturated. My assumption is that if you find a way to limit the degree of parallelism of the `ExecutionLoopX` methods to a number smaller than the [`Environment.ProcessorCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processorcount), your program will behave and perform better. Below is my suggestion for implementing this limitation.

The main obstacle is that currently your `ExecutionLoopX` methods are monolithic: they can't be separated to pieces so that they can be parallelized. My suggestion is to change their return type from `void` to `async Task`, and place an [`await Task.Yield();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.yield) inside the outer loop. This way it will be possible to execute them in steps, with each step being the code from the one `await` to the next.

Then create a `TaskScheduler` with [limited concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.concurrentexclusiveschedulerpair.concurrentscheduler), and a [`TaskFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory) that uses this scheduler:

```
int maxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount - 1;

TaskScheduler scheduler = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair(
    TaskScheduler.Default, maxDegreeOfParallelism).ConcurrentScheduler;

TaskFactory taskFactory = new TaskFactory(scheduler);
```

Now you can parallelize the execution of the methods, by starting the tasks with the [`taskFactory.StartNew`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew) method instead of the `Task.Run`:

```
List<Task> tasks = new();

tasks.Add(taskFactory.StartNew(() => ExecutionLoop1(data)).Unwrap());
tasks.Add(taskFactory.StartNew(() => ExecutionLoop2(data)).Unwrap());
tasks.Add(taskFactory.StartNew(() => ExecutionLoop3(data)).Unwrap());
tasks.Add(taskFactory.StartNew(() => ExecutionLoop4(data)).Unwrap());
//...

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

The [`.Unwrap()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap) is needed because the `taskFactory.StartNew` returns a nested task (`Task<Task>`). The `Task.Run` method [is also doing this unwrapping](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/) internally, when the `action` is asynchronous.

An online demo of this idea can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vJFp5s).

The `Environment.ProcessorCount - 1` configuration means that one CPU core will be available for other work, like the communication with the external API and the updating of the `ConcurrentDictionary`.

<sub>A more cumbersome implementation of the same idea, using iterators and the `Parallel.ForEach` method instead of async/await, can be found in the [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74958744/1) of this answer.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for this. It would be a big change to my program but I think I follow what you are saying and I'll see if it can be implemented within my code.

Comment: @jgriffo1 I updated my answer with a less intrusive implementation of the same idea.

Comment: Thank you again, I'm playing with your sample code that you posted a link to. I should provide more information. Every `Task.Run()` call I make to the `ExecutionLoopX` functions are from an 'OnClick'` event on a button in a GUI.  I thought about `async` and `await` but I need to return control to the GUI and continue operation. I also can't add them in the `BlockingCollection` in one for loop. Although I suppose I can keep adding them as buttons are clicked.

Comment: Finally, I have a question, how are the ExecutionLoop functions actually called in your sample code? Is it simply when they are added to the `BlockingCollection`?

Comment: @jgriffo1 You are probably talking about [the demo of my original answer](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J2umMq). In that demo the `ExecutionLoopX` methods are called when the `Parallel.ForEach` method starts. This method uses also the current thread as a worker, and so it should not be called on the UI thread. You can either wrap it in an `await Task.Run(() => { Parallel.ForEach... });`, or switch to the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) (.NET 6). In either case the `OnClick` event handler should become `async void`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not squeamish about mixing operations in a task, you could redesign such that instead of task A doing A things, B doing B things, C doing C things, etc. you can reduce the number of tasks to the number of processors, and thus run fewer concurrently, greatly easing contention.

So, for example, say you have just two processors. Make a "general purpose/pluggable" task wrapper that accepts delegates. So, wrapper 1 would accept delegates to do A and B work. Wrapper 2 would accept delegates to do C and D work. Then ask each wrapper to spin up a task that calls the delegates in a loop over the dictionary.

This would of course need to be measured. What I am proposing is, say, 4 tasks each doing 4 different types of processing. This is 4 units of work per loop over 4 loops. This is not the same as 16 tasks each doing 1 unit of work. In that case you have 16 loops.

16 loops intuitively would cause more contention than 4.

Again, this is a potential solution that should be measured. There is one drawback for sure: you will have to ensure that a piece of work within a task doesn't affect any of the others.

Comment: That's what the `TaskScheduler`s are doing. They accept cold tasks, and they schedule their execution. Why reinvent a mechanism that already exists?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. If you have 10 tasks each doing something different, you still have 10 loops regardless of when the tasks are scheduled. I'm saying that you have fewer tasks overall, each doing more work per task.

Comment: Admittedly, it may pan out to be the same. There's no way of knowing without measuring.

Comment: There is the built-in [`ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.concurrentexclusiveschedulerpair) class, whose `ConcurrentScheduler` property is a `TaskScheduler` with limited concurrency level. For example if you set the concurrency level to 4, the scheduler will not execute the 5th task before one of the first 4 tasks has completed. Internally it is implemented with a logic similar to what you describe in your answer.